# Question Regarding the Closed Graph Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be Banach spaces and let $ T : X \to Y $ be a linear operator.  The **Closed Graph Theorem** states that $ T $ is continuous on $ X $ if and only if whenever $ (x_n) \subset X $ converges to $ x \in X $ and $ (T(x_n)) $ converges to $ y \in Y $ then $ y = T(x) $.

My question is, does the Closed Graph theorem imply the following: $ T $ is continuous at $ x_0 \in X $ if and only if whenever $ (x_n) \subseteq X $ converges to $ x_0 \in X $ and $ (T(x_n)) $ converges to $ y \in Y $ then $ y = T(x_0)$?

If this is true and since continuity of a $ T $ at $ 0_X $ implies continuity of $ T $ on $ X $, then can the Closed Graph theorem be reformulated as: $ T $ is continuous if and only if whenever $ (x_n) \subseteq X $ converges to $ 0 \in X $ and $ (T(x_n)) $ converges to $ y $ then $ y = T(0) = 0 $?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is exactly right: usually, when we want to show that a function $f$ is continuous, we need to show that if $x_n\to x$ is a convergent sequence, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  What the closed graph theorem tells us is that if $f$ is a linear operator between Banach spaces, then we are allowed to assume in addition that the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to *something*.

Your second question is absolutely right too: indeed, let $x_n\to x$ be a convergent sequence, and let $z_n=x_n-x$, so that $z_n\to 0$.  Assume that $f(x_n)\to y$.  Then $f(z_n)=f(x_n)-f(x)\to y-f(x)$.  If $f$ satisfies your assumptions, then we must have $f(z_n)\to 0$, since $z_n\to 0$, and therefore we have $y-f(x)=0$ and so $y=f(x)$.  By the usual closed graph theorem, this implies that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your response!